# Bitcoin-cli transaction fee reset

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-cli

How do you reset the txfee after you successfully did the transaction? I mean, getting it back to "automatic fee"?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What commands are you using?

Comment: After forcing the bitcoin-cli to use a fixed transaction fee by using the parameter "settxfee", I would like it to automatically revert to the automatic calculation mechanism ( by looking at the last transactions in the blockchain ) . I've read that it automatically resets after 24 hours, but I would like to force such resetting sooner than that. The only way I've found so far is to shutdown the daemon and restarting it.